# Automating the running of a Webmatrix page

Tags: razor, webmatrix, helper

i have created a page in Webmatrix which sends an email to a group of users pull from my database using an SQL query. The page works fine if i just run it, but i'm looking to automate this email to send out at a particular time of day, once a week. What mechanisms should i be using to automate this, windows task scheduler, or is there a helper i can use that's built into webmatrix?

Thanks, Gavin

Comment: This is a good question. If I had to, I know I could probably think of a way to get this done, but it would not be the correct way, nor would it be the most efficient.  I am curious to see the real answer to this question.

Comment: Yeah, I've read somewhere that you might be able to do this using the global.asmx, but I don't know if it's applicable in web pages

Answer (score 1):

The only method I know of is a little bit of a hack, but makes what you're after possible. Using the caching system you can specify a callback that will be called when the data in the cache expires. See the last parameter of this method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.add(v=vs.110).aspx

It's not perfect by a long stretch, but it does allow for arbitrary code execution at either regular intervals or specified times. I'd be interested to hear about any other techniques, especially if they are less hacky.

This link provides full information about implementing the technique, which applies to the entire ASP.NET framework (including WebMatrix):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc